# Auto-compress images when uploaded to Image Library

Tags: 2010, development, image, image-upload

I have a need to auto compress images as they are uploaded to an image library. Using code or otherwise how could I go about this? I don't want to specify a fixed height / width but would rather maintain the aspect ratio and just downsize the image to be under x MB (if at all possible). Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Useful link [image compress](http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=52) that describes compressing images in image library.

Following code will automatically compress image while uploading.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace PictureLibraryImageCrop
{
    public class PictureLibraryEventReciever : SPItemEventReceiver
    {
        public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            try
            {
                //Check user is site admin , remove it if you dont need it
                if (properties.OpenWeb().CurrentUser.IsSiteAdmin)
                {
                    SPFile file = properties.ListItem.File;
                    if (null != file)
                    {
                        properties.OpenWeb().AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        try
                        {
                            MemoryStream msOut = new MemoryStream();
                            MemoryStream msIn = new MemoryStream(file.OpenBinary(), true);

                            int width = 100; //set to desired value 
                            int height = 200; //set to desired value 


                            Image img = Image.FromStream(msIn).GetThumbnailImage(width, height, null, IntPtr.Zero);

                            img.Save(msOut, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                            file.SaveBinary(msOut, false);

                            file.CheckOut();

                            file.Update();

                            file.CheckIn(string.Empty);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            properties.OpenWeb().AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //Do some exception handling 
                throw;
            }

        }

    }

}
```